# C++ function method via function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, class-method

I'm trying to understand how function pointer works can't clarified why I get the following err.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
enum COLOR {RED,BLACK,WHITE};

class Car
{public:
 Car (COLOR c): color(c) { cout<<"Car's constructor..."<<endl; CarsNum++;}
 ~Car () {cout<<"Car's destructor..."<<endl; CarsNum--;}
 void GetColor () { cout<<"Color of the car is"<<color<<endl;}
 static int GetCarsNum () {cout<<"Static membet CarsNum="<<CarsNum<<endl; return 0;}
private:
COLOR color;
static int CarsNum;

};

int Car::CarsNum=0;

int main()
{
int (Car::*pfunc) () = NULL;
pfunc=&Car::GetCarsNum ();


 Car *ptr= new Car(RED);
 ptr->GetColor ();
 ptr->GetCarsNum ();
 delete ptr;
 ptr=0;
 Car::GetCarsNum();
    return 0;
}
```

Err msg:

> `main.cpp|23|error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand`

Problem is with:

```
  pfunc=&Car::GetCarsNum ();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please always indicate the exact line the error message mentions.

Comment: Using `auto` would greatly simplify this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for parentness:

```
pfunc=&Car::GetCarsNum;
```

and

```
int (Car::*pfunc) () = NULL;
```

Oh, UPDATE:
you have static method:
In this case GetCarsNum() is just a simple function:

```
int (*pfunc) () = &Car::GetCarsNum;
```

Comment: Why not mention such small answer in comments

Comment: Because then this question will be without answer:)

Comment: I would rephrase to make it clear that not only is there no *need* for parentheses, the parentheses are actually wrong. (Which is why he was getting the error.)

Comment: @kec, Tejas Patel sorry for my quick, unclear answer

Answer (score 2):

With `&Car::GetCarsNum ()` you are calling `GetCastNum`, and taking the return value to make it a pointer (with the address-of operator `&`).

To solve this simply drop the parentheses:

```
pfunc=&Car::GetCarsNum;
```

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig As the member function is `static` then yes.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The answer does have &, though.

Comment: In this case I got another err:
|23|error: cannot convert 'int()' to 'int (Car::*)()' in assignment|

Comment: @user3604569 Then you need to drop the `Car::` from the declaration of `pfunc`. It's because the `GetCarsNum` is a `static` member function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by putting braces behind the method, you call the method. This confuses the compiler. who now thinks the & operator is used as binary operator.
So remove the () and only specify the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys.
Now I see the diffrence between pointers to **static** method (in this case we use syntaxis as for simple function)

```
int (*pfunc) () = &Car::GetCarsNum;
```

int this case both with '&' and without '&' gives the same result.(and what is the difference).
and calling it:

```
pfunc();
```

And other side - function pointer on standart method:

```
void (Car::*pfunc2) () = NULL;
pfunc2=&Car::GetColor;
```

and calling it:

```
(ptr->*pfunc2)();
```